# Existence of a continuous bijection in the plane

Tags: general-topology

Let $S$ be the unit open ball of $\mathbf{R}^2$ centered in the origin. Does there exists a continuous bijective function
$$f\colon S \to S\cup\{(1,0)\}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The image of an open set in the plane under a continuous bijection to a subset of the plane is open (invariance of domain theorem learns us this). The image is not open here.